# how to make a graphical script that can do routine work on api programs

Tags: linux, windows, bash, api, terminal

I wonder how to make a graphical script ? 
so I can handle routine work on graphical interfaces like on wsus
I think this is possible , gameranger for exemple uses this kind of scripts to get directly to online mode.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use xdialog inside your script to  generate graphical elements.
xdialog is quite powerful and easy to use.

Documentation here: [xdialog.free.fr](http://xdialog.free.fr)